# R: Atomic Number and averages in lists

Tags: r

I am attempting to find the average batting average per team. I have a `matrix` that is similar to what I have below:

```
        bat_avg      team_name  
    [1,] "0.5"        "Rockies"  
    [2,] "0"          "Astros"  
    [3,] "0.5"        "Rockies"  
    [4,] "0"          "Padres"  
    [5,] "0"          "Padres"  
    [6,] "0"          "Rockies"  
    [7,] "0"          "Mets"  
    [8,] "0.4"        "Red Sox"  
    [9,] "0"          "Yankees"  
   [10,] "0"          "Rockies"
```

To find the average bating average per team I tried to transform the matrix into a data frame and attempted to aggregate the data by team name. I am keep receiving the error that my data type is atomic. I am unsure what to do to resolve this problem. I am brand new to R and coding, so thank you for the help!

```
bat_avg <- Batting_average[,26]
team_name <- Batting_average[,100]
Batting_average <- cbind(bat_avg, team_name)
df.Batting_average <- as.data.frame(Batting_average)

aggdata <- aggregate(Batting_average$team_name, by list(Batting_average$bat_avg],
FUN = mean)
```

Below is the top of my data

```
structure(c("0.5", "0", "0.5", "0", "0", "0", "Rockies", "Rockies", 
"Rockies", "Rockies", "Rockies", "Rockies"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L),n.Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("bat_avg", "team_name")))
```

Comment: I have tried to dput() my data, but the length of the data prevents me from posting.

Comment: Create a minimal example then e.g.: dput(head(data))

Comment: I think you need `aggregate(Batting_average$team_name, by = list(Batting_average$bat_avg], FUN = mean)`

Comment: When I try this, I receive the following error.Error in Batting_average$team_name : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that gave reasonable results to me

```
myDf <- data.frame(
  avg = c(0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.4),
  team = c("Rockies", "Rockies", 
    "Rockies", "Rockies", "Rockies", "Rockies", "Astros")
)

myDf
#   avg    team
# 1 0.5 Rockies
# 2 0.0 Rockies
# 3 0.5 Rockies
# 4 0.0 Rockies
# 5 0.0 Rockies
# 6 0.0 Rockies
# 7 0.4 Astros

aggregate(myDf$avg, by = list(myDf$team), FUN  = mean)
#   Group.1         x
# 1  Astros 0.4000000
# 2 Rockies 0.1666667
```

If you want to run this with your data, replace `myDf` with

```
myDf <- data.frame(
  avg = as.numeric(Batting_average[,26]),
  team = as.factor(Batting_average[,100])
)
```

The methods `as.numeric` and `as.factor` might be unnecessary if your data is already in the correct format.

Comment: How would I apply this to my data frame which has 27000 rows? When defining "avg" and "team," how would this differ than what you have?

Comment: The size of the dataset makes no difference in `aggregate`. Just make sure your data is in the right format and run it through this code. I'll edit my answer to make this more clear

Comment: When I entered this into my code. I received the following error "Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate"    Sorry for what may be a foolish question. I have just began working with R.

Comment: Can you start a new R session and check if the error still exists when you copy the whole code in your console?

Comment: The error has now disappeared and results are calculated. Interestingly though, all the mean values are listed as NA, except for one team - the Braves. I am trying to go through my data and now see why that may be....

Comment: Do you have `NA`s in `myDf$avg`?

Comment: Yes. I was able to change them to 0's. Personally, I wish I could keep them as NA's so that it doesn't affect the average though. Do you know a solution that helps resolve this?

Comment: You cn replace `FUN = mean` by `FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)`. Not very elegant, but it will take care of the `NA`s.